# Partial fractions to find $A^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm confused on how to evaluate the individual parts to get the values for $c_1, c_2$

Given the matrix $$A = \begin{bmatrix}2 & 3\\ 3 & 2 \end{bmatrix},$$ I know that $$\det(xI-A) = (x+1)(x-5).$$

Suppose $$\frac{x^n}{f(x)} = q(x)+\frac{c_1}{x+1}+\frac{c_2}{x-5},$$
the solution is shown as:
\begin{align*}
c_1 &= \left.\frac{x^n}{x-5}\right|_{x=-1} = \frac{1}{6} \cdot (-1)^{n+1},\\
c_2 &= \left.\frac{x^n}{x+1}\right|_{x=5} = \frac{1}{6} \cdot 5^{n}.
\end{align*}

I'm not too sure why the first numerator goes to $(-1)^{n+1}$ and not just $(-1)^n$ so some clarification would be nice. Also if we had $(x-5)^2$ what would be the difference in evaluating that?

Comment: Do you have a reference for this method of calculating the nth power? It seems very efficient.

Comment: For your first question: One (-1) comes from -1-5=-6.

Comment: If you have (x-5)^2 then you have to do more work. Calculating the derivative is one possibility.

Comment: http://www.math.ualberta.ca/~xichen/math32517w/ is where he uses it.

Comment: why is it raised to the n+1 power though and not just n or did he make a mistake?

Comment: It is raised to the nth power, and then you get one more -1 from the -6, so you get (-1)^(n+1)

Comment: Ahhh I see it now thank you

Comment: Seems like this parallels the decomposition of $A$ into $5P_1-P_2$, where $P_1$ and $P_2$ are projections onto the respective eigenspaces (and are simple linear combinations of $A$ and $I$) with $P_1P_2=P_2P_1=0$. Then  $A^n=5^nP_1+(-1)^nP_2$.